# Terraform "required_providers" block, configuration_aliases argument

Tags: terraform, hashicorp, terraform-modules

I think of myself as a terraform intermediate that is looking to fine grain its knowledge.

After reading probably 20 times the following documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration

Researching online, and exercising locally. I am not able to understand the function of this highlighted argument

From the docs

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mycloud = {
      source  = "mycorp/mycloud"
      version = "~> 1.0"
      *configuration_aliases = [ mycloud.alternate ]*
    }
  }
}
```

What exactly does "configuration_aliases" do?

It is clear to me that the "provider" block is used to configure the provider with data needed in order to make the API calls. It is clear to me what a provider alias does and that you can call it  (to call for the creation of the same resource using different configuration). But I cannot understand how to use the the configuration_aliases in the required providers.

As of now what I drafted in my pseudo-code is this (it is all in one for simplicity):

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    restapi = {
      source  = "Mastercard/restapi"
      version = "1.18.2"
    }
  }
}
        
provider "restapi" {
  alias                = "main"
  uri                  = "https://my-cortex.io"
  debug                = true
  write_returns_object = true
  headers = {
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Basic ${base64encode("api-key")}"
  }
}
    
module "create_bucket" {
  source = "./modules/create_bucket"
}
```

**main.tf - module create_bucket**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    restapi = {
      source                = "Mastercard/restapi"
      version               = "1.18.2"
      configuration_aliases = [ restapi.main ]
    }
  }
}
        
resource "restapi_object" "s3_bucket_creation_all_off" {
  path = "/api/v1/project/7a274931/services/object-storage/buckets"
  data = <<EOF
    {
       "region": "3cc5e278",
       "label": "to_delete",
       "gb_allocated": 1024,
       "tier": "standard",
       "versioning": false,
       "data_preservation": "none"
    }
EOF
  id_attribute = "result/id" #just to assign a value
  object_id = "update_result" #just to assigna a value
}
```

[image: my directory composition]

When I run the above code, what I get is the following error:

> Error: Missing required provider configuration
> │
> │   on main.tf line 1:
> │    1: module "create_bucket" {
> │
> │ The child module requires an additional configuration for provider
> │ mastercard/restapi, with the local name "restapi.main".
> │
> │ Refer to the module's documentation to understand the intended
> │ purpose of this additional provider configuration, and then add an
> │ entry for restapi.main in the "providers" meta-argument in the
> │ module block to choose which provider configuration the module
> │ should use for that purpose.

What am I missing? I am declaring an alias in the root config then calling the alias inside the required provider inside the module in order to pass a config to the required_provider block so that I don't have to declare the provider block inside the module which is bad practice.

**TL;DR** : configuration_aliases in terraform required providers block. In simple words what does it do? How do you correctly invoke it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#provider-aliases-within-modules.

Comment: I don't understand how to apply it in a real world example. Hashicorp docs are lacking a lot of real world examples for me it is getting uncomprehensible..

Comment: Not really. You did get a really good explanation in the message.

Comment: Can you help further with an example? I can't seem to understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration aliases are usually used when there is a need to deploy a set of resources in more than one region (most commonly related to different cloud providers like AWS, GCP, Azure, etc). This is needed because you cannot have more than one provider block using the same name. Think for example about an API you would need to deploy in the EU and in the USA. Now, in your example, you are using a root module which is using this provider block:

```
provider "restapi" {
  alias                = "main"
  uri                  = "https://my-cortex.io"
  debug                = true
  write_returns_object = true
  headers = {
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
     "Authorization" = "Basic ${base64encode("api-key")}"
  }
}
```

Then, you are calling the child module like this:

```
module "create_bucket" {
  source = "./modules/create_bucket"
}
```

However, the child module is very specific about the provider it expects:

> The child module requires an additional configuration for provider
> │ mastercard/restapi, with the local name "restapi.main".

Or, in terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    restapi = {
      source                = "Mastercard/restapi"
      version               = "1.18.2"
      configuration_aliases = [ restapi.main ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which means that when calling this module in particular, you need to provide the configuration alias it expects. So something like this should work:

```
module "create_bucket" {
  providers = {
    restapi.main = restapi.main # since this is what you used as an alias for the provider in the *root* module
  }
  source = "./modules/create_bucket"
}
```

Finally, the entire code block for the root module should look like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    restapi = {
      source  = "Mastercard/restapi"
      version = "1.18.2"
    }
  }
}

provider "restapi" {
  alias                = "main"
  uri                  = "https://my-cortex.io"
  debug                = true
  write_returns_object = true
  headers = {
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Basic ${base64encode("api-key")}"
  }
}

module "create_bucket" {
  providers = {
    # child module provider name = root module provider name you are passing 
    restapi.main                 = restapi.main
  }  
  source = "./modules/create_bucket"
}
```

So, the short version: the left-hand side is the provider name in the child module (i.e., the module you are calling) while the right-hand side is the provider configuration in the root module (i.e., the module you are calling the child module from). This way you are assigning the root module provider configuration to the child module provider configuration. This is also displayed in the error message:

> │ Refer to the module's documentation to understand the intended
> │ purpose of this additional provider configuration, and then add an
> │ entry for restapi.main in the "providers" meta-argument in the
> │ module block to choose which provider configuration the module
> │ should use for that purpose.

Finally, as this seems like a pet-project, you actually don't need to use configuration aliases at all in this case, since you have only one provider configuration in both root and child modules. You could have easily gotten away with either of the next two:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    restapi = {
      source  = "Mastercard/restapi"
      version = "1.18.2"
    }
  }
}

provider "restapi" {
  uri                  = "https://my-cortex.io"
  debug                = true
  write_returns_object = true
  headers = {
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Basic ${base64encode("api-key")}"
  }
}

module "create_bucket" {
  providers = {
    restapi.main = restapi
  }  
  source = "./modules/create_bucket"
}
```

This still uses the configuration alias in the child module. The second example is without configuration alias:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    restapi = {
      source  = "Mastercard/restapi"
      version = "1.18.2"
    }
  }
}

provider "restapi" {
  uri                  = "https://my-cortex.io"
  debug                = true
  write_returns_object = true
  headers = {
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Basic ${base64encode("api-key")}"
  }
}

module "create_bucket" {
  source = "./modules/create_bucket"
}
```

And then the child module would look like:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    restapi = {
      source  = "Mastercard/restapi"
      version = "1.18.2"
    }
  }
}
    
resource "restapi_object" "s3_bucket_creation_all_off" {
  path = "/api/v1/project/7a274931/services/object-storage/buckets"
  data = <<EOF
    {
        "region": "3cc5e278",
        "label": "to_delete",
        "gb_allocated": 1024,
        "tier": "standard",
        "versioning": false,
        "data_preservation": "none"
    }
EOF
  id_attribute = "result/id" #just to assign a value
  object_id = "update_result" #just to assigna a value
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marko, this saved my day!
I made some tests and tried to change restapi.main = restapi.main into restapi-main = restapi-main but the I find some conflicts within how the modules are called.
Is there a reason if you know why, only the DOT "." is allowed? i believe it's just how terraform is coded..